# Nilpotent Matrices and their products

Tags: linear-algebra

True or False.
For $A,B$ be complex $n \times n$ matrices.
If $AB$ is nilpotent then $BA$ is also nilpotent.

Comment: $AB$ nilpotent means that something like $ABABABABABABABABAB$ equals zero. What does that tell you about $BA$?

Comment: It means BA should also nilpotent

Answer (score 3):

Prove by induction:

$(BA)^n=B(AB)^{n-1}A$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: While any proof of your statement technically involves induction (almost any "for all natural numbers" theorem relies on it in some way; in fact, the very _definition_ of $\Bbb N$ relies on induction, and thus most of regular mathematics), the explicit technique seems overkill here. Just like proof by contradiction, it is a technique people cling to for comfort even when there really is no need, and would just serve to make the proof less readable for people _not_ used to the technique.

Comment: But what if A and B are not commutative

Comment: @user356861 What Fred has written here is basically the same thing as Lord Shark wrote in his comment below your original question. You don't need commutativity for this, just associativity.

Comment: It means we can conclude that whenever AB is nilpotent ,BA Will also

Comment: @Arthur  M I right Sir

Comment: @user356861 If $(AB)^n = 0$, then $(BA)^{n+1} = B(AB)^nA = B0A = 0$, so $BA$ is also nilpotent, although potentially with exponent one higher.

Comment: Thanks you very much sir